# How to save a physics animation?

Tags: animation, physics

I have a file I want to play around with and it takes a long time preview physics animations like rigid body and cloth interactions. However, I hit the play button and after waiting 5 minutes for it to buffer, I like the result. The problem is that if I close the file, blender deletes the rendering of the physics for no reason. How can I save it for the next time I open the file but still modify it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to  bake it. What you did looks probalby like this
[image]
But there  is  a better way to do it. Go to the physiks panel and go to cache.
[image]
Now you have to bake it till the frame that you want it to have.
Now you have a blue that looks like this.
[image]
Now you can save the object and when you open it again, it will stay as it is.

Comment: But doesn't that make the animation permanent then? I just want the physics preview saved.